# Do (quasi)coherent sheaves on a base correspond to sections into some scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal F$ be a locally free sheaf over a scheme or variety $X$. Then we know that $\mathcal F$ can be thought of as sections to a certain vector bundle $E \to X$. Suppose more generally that $\mathcal F$ is only a coherent sheaf, over a nice space like a variety. Can $\mathcal F$ be viewed as sections of some space $E \to X$? Thank you.

Comment: Every sheaf is sections of its etale space.